# MySQL count number of consecutive values of 1 until 0 is hit

Tags: mysql, count, break

I have a bunch of records where a row is inserted every minute of the day. Each row contains a datetime timestamp (time), a value (0 or 1) and a foreign key spotID. There are 100 spots in total.

I need to see how long a value of 1 was held starting from the top between two time stamps: '2017-01-01 00:00:00' and '2017-01-01 00:05:00' (5 hours) for each spot. If a value of 0 is held, the counter stops and moves onto the next spotID.

**Example,** This is my current query I'm using and theoretically how the final query should go through it:

```
SELECT time, value, spotID FROM `records` 
WHERE time BETWEEN '2017-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2017-01-01 05:00:00'
ORDER BY `spotID`, `time` DESC

+------------------------+----------------+-------------+
|    time (datetime)     | value (0 or 1) | spotID (fk) |
+------------------------+----------------+-------------+
| '2017-01-01 05:59:00'  |              1 |           1 |
| '2017-01-01 05:58:00'  |              1 |           1 |
| '2017-01-01 05:57:00'  |              1 |           1 |
| ...consecutive 1's...                                 |
| '2017-01-01 05:30:00'  |              1 |           1 |
| '2017-01-01 05:29:00'  |              0 |           1 |
| ...we hit 0, count 1's and move onto spotID 2...      |
| '2017-01-01 05:59:00'  |              1 |           2 |
| '2017-01-01 05:58:00'  |              1 |           2 |
| '2017-01-01 05:57:00'  |              1 |           2 |
| '2017-01-01 05:56:00'  |              1 |           2 |
| ...consecutive 1's...                                 |
| '2017-01-01 03:42:00'  |              1 |           2 |
| '2017-01-01 03:41:00'  |              0 |           2 |
| ...we hit 0, count 1's and move onto spotID 3...      |
| '2017-01-01 05:59:00'  |              0 |           3 |
| ...we hit 0, count 1's and move onto spotID 4...      |
+------------------------+----------------+-------------+
```

The final query should show (if my math is correct):

```
+--------+---------+
| spotID | minutes |
+--------+---------+
|     1  |      29 |
|     2  |     137 |
|     3  |       0 |
|    ..  |      .. |
|   100  |      .. |
+--------+---------+
```

I'm just not sure how to go through that query above and calculate the sum of consecutive 1's until the first 0 is reached (ignoring any 1's after and just moving onto the next spotID).

**EDIT:**

This is my current query:

```
SELECT a.spotID, SUM(a.value) as minutes
FROM (

    SELECT sr.time, sr.value, sr.spotID FROM `records` as sr
    WHERE sr.time BETWEEN '2017-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2017-01-01 05:00:00'
    ORDER BY sr.spotID, sr.time DESC

) a

GROUP BY a.spotID
```

It's very close however, I still don't know how to get it to exclude any rows after a value of 0. I'm wondering if I need to put a CASE in SUM?

Comment: Does it have to be done in one query?  You could grab MIN and MAX datetime grouped by spot id where value =1 into temp table, then do your minutes calculation?

Comment: No it can be done in multiple, that's fine. Also how would I grab the datetime where the value first equals 0 and then stop at that point? Not sure how to go about this

Comment: You really dont care about the datetime at value=0 right?  Just the one right before it where value=1?

Comment: Going to write a query in the answer below. But bare with me, on my phone.

Answer (score 0):

Well if each row is inserted every min, why don't you just count the number of rows for each spotID.

```
SELECT time,a.spotID,minutes FROM records as a
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT spotID,COUNT(spotID) as minutes FROM records
  WHERE time > [MIN TIME] AND time < [MAX TIME]
  GROUP BY id
  ) b ON a.spotID = b.spotID
WHERE time > [MIN TIME] AND time < [MAX TIME]
ORDER BY time DESC
```

Like this? Not sure if it'll run since I'm just using SQL fiddle.

Comment: I'm not sure if you understood what I'm trying to achieve. I want to look at records between 5 hours (two timestamps), and I want to look at how many values were set to 1 from the top until a value of 0 is reached in each record descending in time for each spot. Your query just goes through every row in the table (around 50 million) and counts how many records there are for each spot. I'm not sure how that's a solution to this.

Comment: Wouldn't the count tell you the number of 1's + 1 for each spotID? if you want to see the number alongside your records then you can inner join my query with yours on spotID.

Comment: I'm not looking for the total number of 1's. I'm looking for the number of consecutive 1's from the top until the value 0 is reached, also within a time frame. Notice how for spotID 1, a value of 29 is calculated by looking at the number of 1's between '2017-01-01 05:59:00' and '2017-01-01 05:29:00' (exclusive). It stops at '2017-01-01 05:29:00'  because that row has a 0, so it needs to count all the 1's before that.

Comment: Your latest query gave back about 89,401 rows, there should only be 100 rows (for each spot). It also gives back minutes as 1 for each row. Again, it needs to count minutes as a sum of each row where the value is 1 until it reaches a 0 from the top, doesn't look like this query is doing that either.

Comment: Yes the one I posted was under the assumption that you simply wanted the values next to the rows. I'll edit the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I would accomplish this in a two step process.

Here is how I solved:

Creating your data:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS bleach;
CREATE TABLE `bleach` (`time` DATETIME, `value` INT, spotID INT);

INSERT INTO bleach (`time`, `value`,spotID) SELECT '2017-01-01 05:59:00',1,1;
INSERT INTO bleach (`time`, `value`,spotID) SELECT '2017-01-01 05:58:00',1,1;
INSERT INTO bleach (`time`, `value`,spotID) SELECT '2017-01-01 05:57:00',1,1;
INSERT INTO bleach (`time`, `value`,spotID) SELECT '2017-01-01 05:30:00',1,1;
INSERT INTO bleach (`time`, `value`,spotID) SELECT '2017-01-01 05:29:00',0,1;
```

Create a temp table and Insert based on spotid

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS bleach2;
CREATE TABLE bleach2 (min_time DATETIME, max_time DATETIME, spotid INT, minutes TIME);

INSERT INTO bleach2 (min_time, max_time, spotID) SELECT MIN(`time`), MAX(`time`), spotID FROM bleach WHERE `value`=1 GROUP BY spotID;
```

Calculate the Time difference:

```
UPDATE bleach2 SET minutes=TIMEDIFF(min_time,max_time);
```

OUTPUT

```
min_time             max_time             spotid     minutes

2017-01-01 05:30:00 2017-01-01 05:59:00    1        -00:29:00
```

Comment: Got a syntax error on this line: UPDATE bleach SET minutes=max_time-min_time, not sure why. Also I don't think this query is accounting for when a value equals 0 and then excluding any rows after.

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Finally at a computer and able to show how I would do this.  Updated answer.

Comment: Getting this error: https://i.imgur.com/l0op4IJ.png Not sure why. MySQL version 5.7 ubuntu 16.04. I have managed to solve it simply with PHP post-processing. Really curious about this error though.

Comment: Happy you solved!  Really weird on that error.  This work?  INSERT INTO bleach (`time`, `value`,spotID) VALUES  ('2017-01-01 05:59:00',1,1);